# ios IDFV store in Keychain

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, keychain, udid

i need **Device ID** which never change, i try **UDID** but is not available in **IOS 6/7/8** so , i try With **IDFV**
I've store **IDFV** in keychain which same after uninstalling app

```
   NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

stored that `idfv` to the Keychain using `SSKeyChain`

When I "Reset content and settings" all stored data in keychain is deleted, and create new **IDFV**. I am new in IOS So I don't know how and where store my string which save my ID permanently.

Answer (score 2):

You don't, Apple  made sure that what you want is not possible, no accessible UDID, MAC address or any other unique device identifiers are available thru the official iOS SDK.
Storing an unique identifier in the keychain is your only option.

Create UUID with the help of [`NSUUID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/index.html) and store it in the keychain.

---

But the main question is why do you want to identify the device, even after the app is uninstalled. There should be no need for it.
If you are going to identify the user by this unique identifier then you will run into a lot of issue later on. Just take in mind that if the user sells it's device and the new user installs the same app the user will identified as the previous owner. Since the device identifier did not change, I've had this happen with some apps.

Comment: When I "Reset content and settings" all stored data in keychain will delete,

Comment: it's App requirement,  identify device and do auto register user, and before sells device it's mandatory the user will delete account or sync with new device, so any way to identify device ?

Comment: Like I've said in my answer and comment **NO** this is not possible and  allowed any more by Apple. Requirement or not, the design is not correct and flawed.